# How are these numbers related?

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

Let's have the following numbers.

34932, 52428, 10023, 1881, 512, 64764, 63012, 57825, 59367, 65508, 30840, 55449, 18009, 65537, 20148, 39321, 62361, 27756.

1. What are the relations between these numbers.
2. How have these numbers been created?

HINT:

> Think Pythagoras

Comment: If you multiply each of them by zero you get zero as a result

Comment: Ι never looked at it that way. You are miles away from the answer.

Comment: It was a joke mate

Comment: They are all positive integers. They can be created by repeatedly adding $1$.

Comment: The answer is far more sophisticated.

Comment: It was again a joke...

Comment: It makes sense that they form Pythagorean pairs, but the exceptional pair $512$ and $65537$ is different from others. Not sure whether it's intended or it actually should be $65535$ instead of $65537$.

Comment: @WhatsUp You are close to the answer. These numbers actually form Pythagorean quadruples. If you think a bit more creatively you will find all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Partial Solution (1):

> You can find 8 Pythagorean quadruples, each containing 512, 65537 and 2 of the remaining numbers.

All of the matches

> 512   34932   55449 65537
> 512   39321   52428 65537
> 512   10023   64764 65537
> 512    1881   65508 65537
> 512   18009   63012 65537
> 512   30840   57825 65537
> 512   27756   59367 65537
> 512   20148   62361 65537

I found them using some Matlab

> a=[34932, 52428, 10023, 1881, 512, 64764, 63012, 57825, 59367, 65508, 30840, 55449, 18009, 65537, 20148, 39321, 62361, 27756];
> b=nchoosek(a,3);
> c=sum(b.^2,2);
> d=a.^2;
> s=find(sum(c==d,1));
> sort(b(c==d(s),:),2)

Comment: @klabuster.These are the correct quadruples. Now you can answer the second question which asks how these numbers were created.

Comment: After reading your hint, are you sure there are only 8 quadruples? 512, 8160, 65025, 65537 is for example another one.

Comment: If found 32 solution that satisfy the conditions of the hint for n=3, there are many for n=4; There are 13 quadrupels with a=65537 and b=512 (b<c<d)

Comment: And  the second question remains to be answered.